# Average Word Length

Tags: java, loops, printing, while-loop, enter

I am attempting to calculate the average word length of user input in Java in a very simplistic way. The actual "math" of the code I've already completed, and it seems to be working quite well, but there are some odd house keeping things I need to address in order to complete the code.

So far, I have the following:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");

    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        String userInput = sc.next();

        double charNum = userInput.length();
        sum = charNum + sum;
        count++;

        double average = 0;
        if (count > 0) {
            average = sum / count;
        }


        System.out.println("Average word length = " + average);

        }
    }
}
```

The end result output should look like this:

```
run: 
Please type some words, then press enter: 
this is a test
Average word length = 2.75
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

However, the output is looking like this:

```
run: 
Please type some words, then press enter: 
this is a test
Average word length = 4.0
Average word length = 3.0
Average word length = 2.3333333333333335
Average word length = 2.75
```

Based on the code that I've written, how can I change it so that:

- The "average word length" is only printed one final time.
- The program ends after the user presses enter

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get `System.out.println(...)` out of the while loop. And declare `average` variable before the loop body.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");

    String words = sc.nextLine();

    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    sc = new Scanner(words);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        String userInput = sc.next();

        double charNum = userInput.length();
        sum = charNum + sum;
        count++;

        if (count > 0) {
            average = sum / count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Average word length = " + average);
}
```

Comment: But when I press enter after submitting some text, the program does not end. The cursor simply moves down a line and waits for me to infinity type more text.

Comment: I understand what you are wanting here.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent solution. Could you perhaps explain a bit how your solution works?

Comment: It might be the best answer since it is closer to your initial code, however it surely isn't an "excellent solution". This can be done in a much clearer way.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question @Dici, but I don't understand your "clearer way" (I am not at that level yet). In this case, any solution which minimally changes the code while also solving my problems is considered excellent. :)

Comment: As a beginner, you shouldn't stick to your solution, which might not be the best, but rather try to understand better solutions from other people. I have edited my post, is it clearer ?

Comment: The problem isn't the clearness of you explanation, it's that it's inconsistent with what we've been learning in class. If I hand in this solution, it will be clear that it is not my work. I am proud that my original calculations within the while loop worked.

Comment: @Dici I don't know what are you saying. This is a simple solution for a simple problem. There is nothing to be done much. How much complexity will you reduce by doing anything in such a small problem. Anyway, it is my answer and I don't want to know if it is excelent or not. This is not the way this site work. Give your answer and you will get repo if you are good enough, that's it.

Comment: Here I agree with you @afzalex. we must give answer that the OP can get easily and that should be upto his level.

Answer (score 3):

You're calculating the average every single time you enter a word, which is not what you want. Also, the while loop will continue even if enter is pressed. Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");

int count = 0;
double sum = 0;

String input = sc.nextLine();

String[] words = input.split("\\s+"); // split by whitespace

// iterate over each word and update the stats
for (String word : words) {
    double wordLength = word.length();
    sum += wordLength;
    count++;
}

// calculate the average at the end
double average = 0;
if (count > 0) {
    average = sum / count;
}

System.out.println("Average word length = " + average);
```

Output:

```
Please type some words, then press enter: 
this is a test
Average word length = 2.75
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your System.out.println after the loop and declare `average` out of the loop to prevent scope issues. However, it is more elegant to do it this way :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");

        double average = 0;

        for (String word : sc.nextLine().split("\\s+")) 
            average += word.length();
        average /= words.length;
        System.out.println("Average word length = " + average);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

`sc.nextLine()` returns the entire line typed by the user (without the last "\n" character) and `split("\\s+")` splits this line using the regex `\s+`, returning an array containing the words. This regex means to split around any non-empty sequence of blank characters.

Comment: I tried this, but the word "average" is not recognized outside of the while loop for some reason. Also, the program does not end when I press enter.

Comment: @Sosika - put average after double sum.

Comment: Yes I forgot yo change the scope of the variable, plus your second point was not verified. Should be fine now !

Comment: This helped "average" to be recognized, but the program is still not ending when I press enter. It simply moves the cursor down.

Comment: Are you sure ? Works fine for me, the logic is good too by the way : we only read one line and then close the Scanner, so th program will exit after completing the average length computation.

Comment: Thanks for your new code suggestion, but alas it changes mine too much (gets rid of the while loop completely). Is there any other way to simply fix mine so that the while loop ends when I press enter?

Answer (score 0):

A) Print your output outside of the loop when all of the averaging has already been done

B) Use `Date.getTime()` to get the time at the start of the program after the user has inputted their sentence, and store it in a variable, then at the end of the program, get the time again, subtract it from the old time, and divide by 1000 to convert it from milliseconds to seconds. After that you can just print it out however you want it formatted

C) call `sc.readLine()` after you have outputted everything so that when they press enter that line will stop blocking and let the program end.

Comment: I am typing sc.readLine();, but readLine is not recognized. Is there a proper way to implement the method into this code?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be `sc.nextLine();` I'm used to BufferedReader